# How to create a synchronized function across all instances

Tags: python, multithreading, decorator

I want to create a synchronized method in python with respect to  some CRUD functions on all instances of a class. For example while create is called and ongoing by a thread, delete needs to wait on the same object.

Can someone please tell me if the code below is correct. I may have some syntax error but what I want to know is if the lock is going to be the same across calls to create ALL instances of this class and therefore if any instance create/delete is in progress delete/create on the same or other instances by another thread will have to wait?

```
import threading
import functools

def synchronized(wrapped):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    @functools.wraps(wrapped)
    def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        with lock:
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrap

class AtomicCRUD(object):

    @synchronized
    def create(self):
        #Do stuff that may take a while here. 
        pass

    @synchronized
    def delete(self):
       #Do stuff that may take a while here. 
       pass
```

My understanding of python is synchronized will be called for each of create/delete function object. **I put a print statement in the synchronized function above for the lock object** and did a test run using the following:

```
@synchronized
def test1():
    print "test1"


@synchronized
def test2():
    print "test2"
```

And I get the following output, which makes me think the lock used is the same for both function objects. I don't seem to understand how this works.

```
<Semaphore c=1 _w[0]>
<Semaphore c=1 _w[0]>
test1
test2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your output prints the same `<Semaphore c=1 _w[0]>` but it doesn't necessarily indicate that those are the same objects. It depends what your `print` statement is.

To make sure you are not using the same `Lock` object you could add a `print` statement in the `_wrap` function as follow:

```
def synchronized(wrapped):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    @functools.wraps(wrapped)
    def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Calling '%s' with Lock %s" % (wrapped.__name__, id(lock))
        with lock:
            return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrap
```

You will get a different [`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) printed every time you call `create` or `delete`:

```
AtomicCRUD().delete()
# Calling 'delete' with Lock 3075170560
AtomicCRUD().delete() 
# Calling 'delete' with Lock 3075170560
AtomicCRUD().create() 
# Calling 'create' with Lock 3075170544                                    
AtomicCRUD().create() 
# Calling 'create' with Lock 3075170544
```

The decorator `synchronized` is only call **twice** - when the interpreter reads the decorated method declaration. The decorator "replace" the decorated method with the implementation of `_wrap` but not with what is above `functools.wraps(wrapped)` so the `Lock` is only created once per decorated method.

Each decorated method has its own `Lock`.

In the code above we can also see that this works for any instance of `AtomicCRUD` since we re-instantiate an object every time but the result is the same when using a single instance

```
crud = AtomicCRUD()                                                             
crud.delete()
# Calling 'delete' with Lock 3075059968                                                             
crud.delete()
# Calling 'delete' with Lock 3075059968
crud.create()
# Calling 'create' with Lock 3075059952
crud.create()
# Calling 'create' with Lock 3075059952
```

And with a complete example we can see that the `Lock`s behave as expected:

```
import threading                                                                
import functools                                                                
import time                                                                     


def synchronized(wrapped):                                                      
    lock = threading.Lock()                                                     
    print lock, id(lock)                                                        
    @functools.wraps(wrapped)                                                   
    def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):                                                 
        with lock:                                                              
            print ("Calling '%s' with Lock %s from thread %s [%s]"              
                   % (wrapped.__name__, id(lock),                               
                   threading.current_thread().name, time.time()))               
            result = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)                                   
            print ("Done '%s' with Lock %s from thread %s [%s]"                 
                   % (wrapped.__name__, id(lock),                               
                   threading.current_thread().name, time.time()))               
            return result                                                       
    return _wrap                                                                

class AtomicCRUD(object):                                                       

    @synchronized                                                               
    def create(self):                                                           
        #Do stuff that may take a while here.                                   
        time.sleep(1)                                                           

    @synchronized                                                               
    def delete(self):                                                           
        #Do stuff that may take a while here.                                   
        time.sleep(1)                                                           


class SyncThread(threading.Thread):                                             

    def __init__(self, crud, name):                                             
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(name=name)                         
        self._crud = crud                                                       

    def run(self):                                                              
        self._crud.create()                                                     
        self._crud.delete()                                                     


crud = AtomicCRUD()                                                             
threads = [SyncThread(crud, "Thread_%d" % i) for i in range(5)]                 
for t in threads:                                                               
    t.start()                                                                   

for t in threads:                                                               
    t.join()
```

The output shows that `create` cannot be called at the same time from different threads. But `delete` and `create` can be called at the same time from different thread.