# How to prevent switching between threads during run of some function. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

**Environment:**
Ubuntu 18.04
Python 3.6.6

**Here is a sample of code:**

```
import threading
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(3)


def thread_run():
    i = 0
    for x in range(10):
        i += 1
        print(x, threading.get_ident())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for x in range(2):
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, thread_run)
    loop.run_forever()
```

**Output:**

```
0 140522512643840
1 140522512643840
2 140522512643840
3 140522512643840
4 140522512643840
5 140522512643840
6 140522512643840
7 140522512643840
0 140522504251136
1 140522504251136
2 140522504251136
3 140522504251136
4 140522504251136
5 140522504251136
6 140522504251136
7 140522504251136
8 140522504251136
9 140522504251136
8 140522512643840
9 140522512643840
```

**Questions:** 
How I can prevent switching "context" for `thread_run` function?
How to make some function "atomic"?
Expected result(with keeping several threads):

```
0 140522512643840
...
9 140522512643840
0 140522504251136
...
9 140522504251136
```

**PS:** required to keep method of calling `thread_run` (loop.run_in_executor). This is just simplified example. I'm asking only about case, which is described in example. I know, there are many way to refactor code and get rid of `loop.run_in_executor`, but I try to find solution in this particular case.

**PSS:** same behavior in Windows 10 (loops increased up to 100)

```
67 8704
16 14712
68 8704
69 8704
70 8704
17 14712
71 8704
```

**Update: #1**
I was trying use decocator: (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29163532/4436022))

```
def synchronized(wrapped):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    @functools.wraps(wrapped)
    def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        with lock:
            result = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
```

But it doesn't work for several functions:

```
import threading
import asyncio
import functools
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(3)


def synchronized(wrapped):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    @functools.wraps(wrapped)
    def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        with lock:
            result = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
            return result

    return _wrap


@synchronized
def thread_run():
    i = 0
    for x in range(5):
        i += 1
        print(x, "thread_run", threading.get_ident())


@synchronized
def thread_run2():
    i = 0
    for x in range(5):
        i += 1
        print(x, "thread_run2", threading.get_ident())


def not_important():
    i = 0
    for x in range(5):
        i += 1
        print(x, "not_important", threading.get_ident())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_in_executor(executor, thread_run)
    loop.run_in_executor(executor, thread_run2)
    loop.run_in_executor(executor, not_important)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Output:

```
0 thread_run 140039310980864
0 thread_run2 140039302588160
0 not_important 140039220623104
1 not_important 140039220623104
2 not_important 140039220623104
1 thread_run2 140039302588160
2 thread_run2 140039302588160
3 thread_run2 140039302588160
4 thread_run2 140039302588160
3 not_important 140039220623104
4 not_important 140039220623104
1 thread_run 140039310980864
2 thread_run 140039310980864
3 thread_run 140039310980864
4 thread_run 140039310980864
```

**Expected:**
Each function(except `not_important`) is run in sequence. Not in parallel.

**Update #2:**
I've added answer with "half" solution. But it doesn't solve problem, when you want to "makr" one function, which should not be interupted with any other function.

Comment: That decorator approach only breaks because the decorator creates the lock, hence you end up with one lock per decorated function that they can acquire exclusively. In order to synchronize the functions there may only be one lock. If you move the `lock = threading.Lock()` from the decorator to the beginning of your `__name__ == '__main__'` block it should do what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

**Current solulion** (not totally solved) is based on comment @shmee

```
import threading
import asyncio
import functools
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(3)


def synchronized(wrapped):
    @functools.wraps(wrapped)
    def _wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        with lock:
            result = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
            return result

    return _wrap


@synchronized
def thread_run():
    i = 0
    for x in range(10):
        i += 1
        print(x, "thread_run", threading.get_ident())


@synchronized
def thread_run2():
    i = 0
    for x in range(10):
        i += 1
        print(x, "thread_run2", threading.get_ident())


def not_important():
    i = 0
    for x in range(10):
        i += 1
        print(x, "not_important", threading.get_ident())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = threading.Lock()  # global lock

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for x in range(5):
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, thread_run)
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, thread_run2)
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, not_important)
    loop.run_forever()
```

**Output**:

```
0 thread_run 140192637171456
1 thread_run 140192637171456
2 thread_run 140192637171456
3 thread_run 140192637171456
4 thread_run 140192637171456
5 thread_run 140192637171456
6 thread_run 140192637171456
7 thread_run 140192637171456
8 thread_run 140192637171456
9 thread_run 140192637171456
0 thread_run2 140192637171456
1 thread_run2 140192637171456
2 thread_run2 140192637171456
3 thread_run2 140192637171456
4 thread_run2 140192637171456
5 thread_run2 140192637171456
6 thread_run2 140192637171456
7 thread_run2 140192637171456
8 thread_run2 140192637171456
9 thread_run2 140192637171456
0 not_important 140192620386048
1 not_important 140192620386048
2 not_important 140192620386048
3 not_important 140192620386048
0 thread_run 140192637171456
1 thread_run 140192637171456
2 thread_run 140192637171456
3 thread_run 140192637171456
4 thread_run 140192637171456
5 thread_run 140192637171456
6 thread_run 140192637171456
7 thread_run 140192637171456
8 thread_run 140192637171456
9 thread_run 140192637171456
0 thread_run2 140192637171456
1 thread_run2 140192637171456
2 thread_run2 140192637171456
3 thread_run2 140192637171456
4 thread_run2 140192637171456
4 not_important 140192620386048
5 not_important 140192620386048
6 not_important 140192620386048
7 not_important 140192620386048
8 not_important 140192620386048
9 not_important 140192620386048
0 not_important 140192620386048
1 not_important 140192620386048
2 not_important 140192620386048
3 not_important 140192620386048
4 not_important 140192620386048
5 not_important 140192620386048
6 not_important 140192620386048
7 not_important 140192620386048
8 not_important 140192620386048
9 not_important 140192620386048
5 thread_run2 140192637171456
6 thread_run2 140192637171456
7 thread_run2 140192637171456
8 thread_run2 140192637171456
9 thread_run2 140192637171456
0 not_important 140192637171456
1 not_important 140192637171456
2 not_important 140192637171456
3 not_important 140192637171456
4 not_important 140192637171456
5 not_important 140192637171456
0 thread_run 140192620386048
1 thread_run 140192620386048
6 not_important 140192637171456
7 not_important 140192637171456
8 not_important 140192637171456
9 not_important 140192637171456
2 thread_run 140192620386048
3 thread_run 140192620386048
4 thread_run 140192620386048
5 thread_run 140192620386048
6 thread_run 140192620386048
7 thread_run 140192620386048
8 thread_run 140192620386048
9 thread_run 140192620386048
0 thread_run2 140192628778752
1 thread_run2 140192628778752
2 thread_run2 140192628778752
3 thread_run2 140192628778752
4 thread_run2 140192628778752
5 thread_run2 140192628778752
6 thread_run2 140192628778752
7 thread_run2 140192628778752
8 thread_run2 140192628778752
9 thread_run2 140192628778752
0 thread_run 140192637171456
1 thread_run 140192637171456
2 thread_run 140192637171456
3 thread_run 140192637171456
4 thread_run 140192637171456
5 thread_run 140192637171456
6 thread_run 140192637171456
7 thread_run 140192637171456
0 not_important 140192628778752
1 not_important 140192628778752
2 not_important 140192628778752
3 not_important 140192628778752
4 not_important 140192628778752
5 not_important 140192628778752
6 not_important 140192628778752
7 not_important 140192628778752
8 not_important 140192628778752
9 not_important 140192628778752
8 thread_run 140192637171456
9 thread_run 140192637171456
0 thread_run2 140192620386048
1 thread_run2 140192620386048
2 thread_run2 140192620386048
3 thread_run2 140192620386048
4 thread_run2 140192620386048
5 thread_run2 140192620386048
6 thread_run2 140192620386048
7 thread_run2 140192620386048
8 thread_run2 140192620386048
9 thread_run2 140192620386048
0 thread_run 140192628778752
1 thread_run 140192628778752
2 thread_run 140192628778752
3 thread_run 140192628778752
4 thread_run 140192628778752
5 thread_run 140192628778752
6 thread_run 140192628778752
7 thread_run 140192628778752
8 thread_run 140192628778752
9 thread_run 140192628778752
0 not_important 140192637171456
1 not_important 140192637171456
2 not_important 140192637171456
3 not_important 140192637171456
4 not_important 140192637171456
5 not_important 140192637171456
0 thread_run2 140192620386048
1 thread_run2 140192620386048
2 thread_run2 140192620386048
3 thread_run2 140192620386048
4 thread_run2 140192620386048
5 thread_run2 140192620386048
6 thread_run2 140192620386048
7 thread_run2 140192620386048
8 thread_run2 140192620386048
9 thread_run2 140192620386048
6 not_important 140192637171456
7 not_important 140192637171456
8 not_important 140192637171456
9 not_important 140192637171456
```

**Current result**: 
Functions `thread_run` and  `thread_run2` is not clashed. But they could be interrupted by `not_important` function. 

So this partially solve my question. I would like to find way to prevent interrupting `thread_run` and  `thread_run2` functions by any other functions. Because in real project there are many other methods/functions and I can't add `synchronized` for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

`run_in_executor` returns a future, that you may await to archive sequential execution

```
import asyncio
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(3)

def thread_run():
    i = 0
    for x in range(10):
        i += 1
        print(x, threading.get_ident())

async def run(loop):
    for _ in range(2):
        await loop.run_in_executor(executor, thread_run)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(run(loop))
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: yeap, but it's just case for "refactoring". As I mentioned in `PSS` section: I don't want to refactor anything. just try to find solution in current code case. + My example is just simplified. There are many threads with different functions and I need to protect only one function.

Comment: And main question is "how to propect function from switching of context?". You can imagen, then you have 16+ threads with many currently running function. And in this situation I try to find way to protect separate function from other threads.