# How to make sure that 2 coroutines are executed one JUST after the other inside another coroutine?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to delete multiple items concurrently using asyncio and aiohttp. I'm using asyncio.gather() for that:

```
import aiohttp

from time import time
from typing import List

# This is stored in a dedicated token manager, here put for simplicity
token = "access_token"

# Gets a new token from Keycloak if the old one has already expired or returns the old token
def get_access_token():
    if token.expires_at > time():
        token = "new_token" # Keycloak call
    else:
        return token


async def delete_single_item(
        self,
        session: aiohttp.ClientSession,
        url: str
    ):
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {get_access_token()}" # this token needs to be valid when delete() is called below!
        }
        async with session.delete(
            url=url,
            headers=headers,
            ssl=self.ssl_context
        ) as resp:
            return await resp.text()


async def _delete_all_items(delete_url, items: List):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for item in items:            
            tasks.append(
                asyncio.ensure_future(
                    delete_single_item(
                        session,
                        delete_url.format(id=item["identifier"])
                    )
                )
            )
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


def delete_all_items(items: List):
    delete_url = "some_url"
    return asyncio.run(_delete_all_items(delete_url, items))
```

As you can see inside *delete_single_item()* I'm obtaining a token (either a new one if the old one has expired or the old one from memory) and then call *session.delete()* to make the actual REST API call with the token.

The problem is that even though getting the token and calling *session.delete()* is defined inside the coroutine *delete_single_item()* one line below the other what I observe for let's say 1000 objects is that first *get_access_token()* is called 1000 times and then *session.delete()* is called 1000 times. As a result, sometimes the token is already expired by the time *session.delete()* is called.

How do I prevent that? How do I make sure that getting the token and calling *session.delete()* is "atomic" - it always happen together or doesn't happen at all? Is it even possible with asyncio?

As a workaround I'm grouping my futures into smaller groups (for example 10 groups of 100 items for 1000 items) and then it works (the token does not expire by the time 100 API calls are made) but it's obviously not a perfect solution.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551823/how-to-prevent-switching-between-threads-during-run-of-some-function-python

Comment: Thanks @matszwecja. I understand you mean the "lock" solution? This works but it limits concurrency significantly. Is there no other way to achieve what I want? Is the "batching" solution which I implemented as far as one can go to prevent token expiration but at the same time keep decent performance?